# Why there's no proxy support in Android browsers?

Tags: browser, proxy

Android supports both Chromium-based and Firefox-based browsers since long now.

While those browsers have full support for HTTP/SOCKS proxies under all other OSes (Linux, OSX and even Windows), they are lacking it completely under Android. There's no setting at all to configure one.

I can easily configure a SOCKSv5 proxy on my Android device with, say, `ssh -D` to be used over whatever connections I have (wifi, ethernet, mobile data...), but I cannot use it with my browsers.

There's some system-wide support when you configure wifi, but that's not what I talk about. **I mean the good ol' *application-level* proxy support**. I don't want to send **all** traffic through a proxy, but just that for a specific browser on demand.

For the curious, I am asking this because I need and can compare results on my landline Internet link, but I cannot do the same on my mobile one.

Please, **forget about VPNs** which are also system-wide solutions like wifi proxies. I need to configure a proxy on a *per-browser* basis, just like I can do on a PC, and not a VPN.

So, why this lack?

Comment: Firefox has some proxy settings in about:config on Android, but they never worked properly for me. You can try them.

Comment: VPN isn't necessarily a system-wide solution. You can select even a single app using UID-based filtering.

Comment: The question here hasn't been answered, WHY?  Google doesn't want it to be possible to proxy traffic from the browser?  I'm currently located in Russia, which invaded Ukraine a week ago - this night BBC got blocked, and that's probably just the beginning.  Proxying web traffic to certain sites, both from laptop and mobile is really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no apparent "technical" reason for that lack. I suspect it'd be something related to the "Android Program Policy" (or whatever else it's called).
In my opinion it looks like an intentional choice as the system-level proxy you can normally configure could be leaking information for some reason or bug.

Anyway, we can configure the SOCKSv5 proxy for [Firefox for Android prior to version 68.11](https://www.mozilla.org/it/firefox/channel/android/#beta), but there seems to be no way to do the same for Chrome/Chromium.

Provided that you already established such a proxy, for example with a suitable SSH client (`-D` option).

1. In Firefox address bar type: `about:config`. A page full of settings will pop up.
2. In the search box type `network.proxy` to reduce the settings to those we are interested in.
3. For a SOCKv5 proxy you can set:
4. `network.proxy.socks` to the proxy IP address
5. `network.proxy.socks_port` to the proxy TCP port
6. `network.proxy.type` to `1` for *manual proxy configuration*
7. (optional) `network.proxy.no_proxies_on` to address that need not to be proxied (or clean it up to reach remote loopback addresses)
8. For a "*regular*" HTTP proxy, any other proxy type or even any other setting that's not available in the setting menu, please refer to the above settings page and to the [official online documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Knowledge_Base).

**N.B.** Starting with **v68.11** Firefox for Android doesn't provide anymore access to settings via the `about:config` pseudo-page, even if it's listed in `about:about` pseudo-page. This is not mentioned within the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/android/68.11.0/releasenotes/) and means that there's no way anymore to use a proxy within a browser.
However [Firefox Nightly releases still allow users to access about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/lt/questions/1300502), you can install theses builds to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use [Bromite](https://www.bromite.org/). Bromite is a Chromium fork with ad blocking and privacy enhancements

Comment: Is Bromite still maintained at all? There have been no commits in [their source repo](https://github.com/bromite/bromite) since January.

Comment: Please @afnan add directions and/or details.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually a plugin to Firefox on Android called Foxyproxy  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/foxyproxy-standard/ that handles the proxy settings for Firefox

Comment: No longer available.

Comment: Well @EnzoR, I'm running it... I downloaded it

Comment: ..I've contacted the author, and he's investigating why the plugin isn't available, because according to him, it still should be..

Comment: Nonetheless there is no plugin available (any more?) and thus no solution or workaround.